# Plotly R add_trace objects are far apart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart with a smaller width than usual. When I try reducing the width, there are gaps between the bars which I would not want. Is there any way to change that? A way to make two bars stick next to each other?

I have reproduced the code below:

```
    library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals)%>%
add_trace(y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar',width=0.25, name = 'SF Zoo')%>%
add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo,type='bar',width=0.25, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
 layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

Also, I would want the value of the bar chart to be displayed at the bottom of the chart. I tried but was only able to get it inside the bar but displayed at the top of the bar and not the bottom.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to `ggplotly` (mix of plotly and ggplot2) it might be easier to get what you want, especially the annotations.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys", "giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
Zoos <- c("SF_Zoo", "SF_Zoo", "SF_Zoo", "LA_Zoo", "LA_Zoo", "LA_Zoo")
Values <- c(20, 14, 23, 12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, Zoos, Values)

p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Animals, y=Values, fill = Zoos, text = Values)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), width = 0.25)+ 
geom_text(label = Values, position = position_dodge(0.2), aes(y = 5)) + 
theme_bw()
ggplotyly(p)
```

Comment: I am trying to incorporate this graph on a Shiny app. Have not tried ggplotly. Will try and use this. Thank you :)

Comment: ggplotly works well with shiny. If it answers your question, don't forget to accept it!

Comment: Will just try it sir. to render it in shiny, we use the same command as that for plotly?